# Web Site URL for analytics-tracking in a Spotify-App?

Tags: google-analytics, spotify

I want to track pageviews and userinteractions in a Spotify-app.
Spotify says it's possible: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/#usertrackinganalytics

Which »Web Site URL« do i enter when setting up a property for analytics-tracking in a Spotify-App?

Or am I doing it wrong and have to do it in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

You can use a fake one if you will.

The only place where GA uses that is when creating links back from the reports to your website. Since your website doesn't exist, it's more like an extension from what I understand. Then you don't need those links anyway.

If feeling not-creative just use:

http://my-spotify-app.com